# Suggestions for speeding up Random Forests

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm doing some work with the `randomForest` package and while it works well, it can be time-consuming.  Any one have any suggestions for speeding things up?  I'm using a Windows 7 box w/ a dual core AMD chip.  I know about R not being multi- thread/processor, but was curious if any of the parallel packages (`rmpi`, `snow`, `snowfall`, etc.) worked for `randomForest` stuff.  Thanks.

EDIT:

I'm using rF for some classification work (0's and 1's).  The data has about 8-12 variable columns and the training set is a sample of 10k lines, so it's decent size but not crazy.  I'm running 500 trees and an mtry of 2, 3, or 4.

EDIT 2: 
Here's some output:

```
> head(t22)
  Id Fail     CCUse Age S-TFail         DR MonInc #OpenLines L-TFail RE M-TFail Dep
1  1    1 0.7661266  45       2 0.80298213   9120         13       0  6       0   2
2  2    0 0.9571510  40       0 0.12187620   2600          4       0  0       0   1
3  3    0 0.6581801  38       1 0.08511338   3042          2       1  0       0   0
4  4    0 0.2338098  30       0 0.03604968   3300          5       0  0       0   0
5  5    0 0.9072394  49       1 0.02492570  63588          7       0  1       0   0
6  6    0 0.2131787  74       0 0.37560697   3500          3       0  1       0   1
> ptm <- proc.time()
> 
> RF<- randomForest(t22[,-c(1,2,7,12)],t22$Fail
+                    ,sampsize=c(10000),do.trace=F,importance=TRUE,ntree=500,,forest=TRUE)
Warning message:
In randomForest.default(t22[, -c(1, 2, 7, 12)], t22$Fail, sampsize = c(10000),  :
  The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?
> proc.time() - ptm
   user  system elapsed 
 437.30    0.86  450.97 
>
```

Comment: Can you describe your data and modeling in a bit more detail?  That will help a bit in making suggestions on how to address improvements.

Comment: You can often get rf models of equivalent performance only drawing a subsample of your data for each tree (`sampsize`), rather than a resample of size 10k for each tree.

Comment: I'm currently using the sampsize option.  However the runs still take 5-10 minutes depending on number of trees, variables, etc.

Comment: I can run a rf model on 10k observations and 500 trees with 8 variables _without_ using the `sampsize` argument _and_ using the formula interface in under 15 seconds on my year old macbook air. I suspect there's something else going on.

Comment: It would really help if you posted code to create sample data and the code you're actually running (i.e. a reproducible example).

Comment: Are those 12 variables stored as factors in the input data? If they are, are there many levels? As @joran says, don't use the formula interface; that is for convenience not speed. Are you sure you are not maxing out the RAM on your machine during fitting (i.e. are your discs swapping memory into/out of RAM)? 10K rows doesn;t seem like very much to me.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The manual of the `foreach` package has a section on Parallel Random Forests 
([Using The foreach Package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf), Section 5.1):

```
> library("foreach")
> library("doSNOW")
> registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(4, type="SOCK"))

> x <- matrix(runif(500), 100)
> y <- gl(2, 50)

> rf <- foreach(ntree = rep(250, 4), .combine = combine, .packages = "randomForest") %dopar%
+    randomForest(x, y, ntree = ntree)
> rf
Call:
randomForest(x = x, y = y, ntree = ntree)
Type of random forest: classification
Number of trees: 1000
```

If we want want to create a random forest model with a 1000 trees, and our computer has four
cores, we can split up the problem into four pieces by executing the `randomForest` function four times, with the `ntree` argument set to 250. Of course, we have to combine the resulting `randomForest` objects, but the `randomForest` package comes with a function called `combine`.

Comment: Unfortunately we loose some outputs when using parallel computations, such as the R²

Comment: Stephane, Why does this happen?

Comment: I run parallel RF and when I call print(rf) it doesn't show confusion matrix anymore. is there way to get confusion matrix?

Comment: @rcs As hmi2015 mentioned, how can we get the confusion matrix in this case?

Comment: @hmi2015 Did you find a way to print confusion matrix in this case?

Comment: @rcs I am working on a university's cluster and there if I reserve 4 nodes (each have 12 cores) then can I use it like this: `registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(48, type="SOCK"))` `rf <- foreach(ntree=rep(22,48), .combine=combine, .packages="randomForest") %dopar% randomForest(trainData[,-1], trainData$Class, ntree=ntree, norm.votes=FALSE)` ?? Actually by using this way, I can see the load is only on 1 node and then it ran out of memory. Can you guide me how can I overcome this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

There are two 'out of the box' options that address this problem. First, the caret package contains a method 'parRF' that handles this elegantly. I commonly use this with 16 cores to great effect. The randomShrubbery package also takes advantages of multiple cores for RF on Revolution R.

Comment: Hi Brent, in Revolution R does randomShrubbery take .xdf as input dataset or does have to be a dataframe. I have a 10GB .xdf training file.

Comment: It's part of the train function though, so you won't find it with ?parRF, instead do ?train and read up. This answer is the better way forward really, cheers Brent

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use an already parallelized and optimized implementation of Random Forest? Have a look to SPRINT using MPI.
http://www.r-sprint.org/

Answer (score 4):

Is there any particular reason why you're not using Python (namely the scikit-learn and multiprocessing modules) to implement this? Using joblib, I've trained random forests on datasets of similar size in a fraction of the time it takes in R. Even without multiprocessing, random forests are significantly faster in Python. Here's a quick example of training a RF classifier and cross validating in Python. You can also easily extract feature importances and visualize the trees.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import *
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

#assuming that you have read in data with headers
#first column corresponds to response variable 
y = data[1:, 0].astype(np.float)
X = data[1:, 1:].astype(np.float)

cm = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 0]])
precision = np.array([])
accuracy = np.array([])
sensitivity = np.array([])
f1 = np.array([])
matthews = np.array([])

rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_features = 5, n_jobs = 2)

#divide dataset into 5 "folds", where classes are equally balanced in each fold
cv = StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds = 5)
for i, (train, test) in enumerate(cv):
        classes = rf.fit(X[train], y[train]).predict(X[test])
        precision = np.append(precision, (precision_score(y[test], classes)))
        accuracy = np.append(accuracy, (accuracy_score(y[test], classes)))
        sensitivity = np.append(sensitivity, (recall_score(y[test], classes)))
        f1 = np.append(f1, (f1_score(y[test], classes)))
        matthews = np.append(matthews, (matthews_corrcoef(y[test], classes)))
        cm = np.add(cm, (confusion_matrix(y[test], classes)))

print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (accuracy.mean(), accuracy.std() * 2))
print("Precision: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (precision.mean(), precision.std() * 2))
print("Sensitivity: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (sensitivity.mean(), sensitivity.std() * 2))
print("F1: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (f1.mean(), f1.std() * 2))
print("Matthews: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (matthews.mean(), matthews.std() * 2))
print(cm)
```

Comment: As far as I know, Python doesn't have implemented importance as  "mean decrease accuracy". (measure the decrease in accuracy on OOB data when you randomly permute the values for that feature). As my primary task is feature selection, this is decisive in my case.