# Get caret to print progress

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to optimize a xgboost tree by using feature selection with caret's genetic algorithm

```
results <- gafs(iris[,1:4], iris[,5],
               iters = 2,
               method = "xgbTree",
               metric = "Accuracy",
               gafsControl = gafsControl(functions=caretGA, method="cv", repeats=2, verbose = TRUE),
               trConrol = trainControl(method = "cv", classProbs = TRUE, verboseIter = TRUE)
               )
```

this is however very slow and thus I would like to plot a progress bar. However I do not get any progress plotted, even though I used `verbose = TRUE` and `verboseIter = TRUE`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `xgbTree` is just taking forever. Eventually you would see `Fold01 ....`, but that's all, no plotted progress.

Comment: @JuliusVainora: I thought the point of xgboost is that is much faster in training than other boosted methods. Have I been mislead? What other method should I take instead? Other methods also took quite a long time. For now I just want to demonstrate "gafs" - what method should I use instead?

Comment: The default one, random forest, seems to be faster.

Comment: @JuliusVainora: This sounds like the opposite of what https://stackoverflow.com/a/32946722/4533188 says.

Comment: Well, I simply got to see `Fold01 ....` much earlier with random forest than `xgbTree`. And I'm not sure what's opposite: it says that ranger > randomForest, xgboost.